# Trimble Data Transfer won't convert files

Tags: convert, error, trimble, data-transfer

I was importing files from Trimble Recon for over 3 years and this never happened with me.

When I conect my controller and select the file to import, the file load 100% and when start to convert appear this error.
I tried in 5 computers and 4 controllers recon too.

Asked to local support but they can't find the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a repair tool you can use to fix the file. I can't recall exactly where it is though. I believe you can go to the file manager on Terrasync to access it and repair the file on the device.  You can also cut the parts off of the unit that make up the SSF file and repair it via GPS Pathfinder office and you should end up with a valid SSF file once the repair has been completed. One thing I remember though if you are using real-time corrections, there is an age limit on correcting those files so I wouldn't wait too long.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some problem with the files.  If you have a support contract, contact Trimble Support and they may be able to help.  If you don't have a Support contract (they are rather expensive), you will probably need to collect the data again!

Before you go out and collect data again, collect a short SSF file on the Recon and check that it can be transferred to the PC - it may be that something has broken / stopped working (WNRO may have affected older TerraSync versions, I can't remember.)